# IIS6 access denied error 401.3

Tags: iis, iis-6, acl

If I have windows authentication enabled, anonymous and basic disabled for an individual aspx page in iis6  and in the acl only my user (That I'm logged in as) has full permissions to that file, no other account has been added to the list.

Why do I get an 401.3 access is denied error when the credentials are correct. The credentials box just keeps appearing. I have removed inheritance from the parent directory incase there were any deny permissions, i have checked my account isn't locked and I've even tried using fiddler to see if I can find any problems but I find it confusing.

The only way I could get the page to show is by adding the everyone group into the acl which makes me think even though I have specified windows authentication,it's still using another account but i don't know which one? I tried adding the IUSR account into  the acl but still no luck.

Could it be something to do with NTML and kerberos. on fiddler, it says:

WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Negotiate

WWW-Authenticate Header is present: NTLM


But I don't know if this is correct ( a bit out my league). So any tips or ideas to look at would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may have done this already, given your comment about IUSR account, but... Double-check that the app pool identity for this application has Read & Execute access to the files on the file system. The App Pool identity could be Network Service, a domain service account, or a builtin account. If that account doesn't have access, IIS won't be able to read the file to serve it to you.

Comment: So does the app pool identity override the windows authentication?

Comment: @Daniel I added in the network service and it worked, thanks. I can't mark your comment as an answer

Comment: It's not so much overriding the authentication model... To serve a resource, 2 accounts must have access to the resource: 1) the requester, to confirm based on file ACL that user has permission to the file, and 2) the app pool identity, to allow IIS to actually read and serve the page to the requester over HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

401.3 is Unauthorized due to ACL on resource. I would run Process Monitor, reproduce the issue, and search for Access Denied. Then fix the errors by providing appropriate permissions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/01/18/using-filemon-regmon-to-solve-quot-access-denied-quot-issues.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very old but make sure these users have access to the main folder of your website:

IUSER,
Network Services
IIS_IUSERS

read and execute is enough